# random error on parsing json

Tags: php, json, parsing

I use the current function to parse json file :

```
   function getRemoteJson($uri, $decode=true, $noob=false){
     if($uri){
       $fp = fopen($uri, "r");
       $json = trim(file_get_contents($fp));
       fclose($fp);

      if($decode) return json_decode($json, true);
      else return $json;
      }
     else return false;
   }
```

That works fine with this file :
http://webcast-a.live.sportingpulse.com/matches/3886/09/18/90/33S64Il4cTaxQ/data.json

But that return me null when I use that one :
http://webcast-a.live.sportingpulse.com/matches/3886/09/18/94/84Q4GEVlZs4rg/data.json

No error code when I parse this file (ie json_last_error() return JSON_ERROR_NONE )

And when I use an online tool to check the format, the file is parsed...

Thanks if you had any clue

Comment: Is the second json file read? Does var_dump($json) return anything? You are supressing the errors when reading files... Take out @ signs and see if it causes any errors.

Comment: Here what I have after the var_dump($json) return me : null

and when I use that tool : http://json.parser.online.fr/
the file is correctly parsed

Comment: Then its not being read. Remove the @ signs and see why.

Comment: There are no valid situation in which you should use the @ to silence errors. You should NEVER use it.

Comment: No error dispayed when I remove the @ signs...

Comment: Where did you put the var_dump?

Comment: I simply do :
$uri = '';
$data = getRemoteJson($uri true);
var_dump($data);

Comment: So I found...
OK, I found the trouble... I hve try on another server and I got a JSON_ERROR_UTF8 error.

So IN my function getRemoteJson() if modify the line

$json = trim(file_get_contents($fp));

by

 $json = utf8_encode(trim(stream_get_contents($fp)));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the trouble... I hve try on another server and I got a JSON_ERROR_UTF8 error.

So if modify the code as following :

```
function getRemoteJson($uri, $decode=true, $noob=false, $utf8_error = false){
 if($uri):
   $fp = fopen($uri, "r");
   if($utf8_error) $json = utf8_encode(trim(stream_get_contents($fp))); 
        else $json = trim(stream_get_contents($fp)); 
        fclose($fp);

        $data = json_decode($json, true);

        if(is_array($data)) return $data;   

        else
            if(!$utf8_error) return getRemoteJson($uri, $decode, true, true);
            else return false;
    else:
        return false;
    endif;
    }
```